# How to reference methods and fields without hardcoded names?

Tags: java, methods, field

I need to register fields in a validation registerer object for later validations, it is something like this;

```
public class ValidationRegisterer{

    public void register(String spElPath, Validator validator){
        //puts spElPath and the related validator into a collection...
    }

}
```

Suppose I have a A class;

```
public class A {
    private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And I want to validate name field of A objects, then I'm registering a Validator like this;

```
validationRegisterer.register("name", MandatoryFieldValidator.class);
```

validationRegisterer has been set up to use A class as root so it knows it should look up A class to get "name". For retrieving the values and registering validators, I'm using Spring Expression Language (SpEl).

But I don't want to hardcode field names like "name" in this example because, someone could do a refactor and change the field names without changing the registration paths and we could not detect this until a runtime exception occurs. Is there a way to store references of field names and methods of classes like Hibernate Metadata Generated classes?

Comment: I do believe you're looking for this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: `private` fields are private for a reason. You **should not** be validating them in an external class. Better do the validation on the accessor methods -- *their* names, as a public contract, are *a lot less likely* to be changed

Comment: Reflection can help you.

Comment: Actually with SpEl I'm using the accessor methods, not the fields values directly. When I use "name" as SpEl expression, getName method is invoked.

I don't know how Reflection can help me. I don't want to hardcode field names and with Reflection I don't think it will be possible to know which Validator to register without hardcoding the field name.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you perform validation yourself at the point where the field is assigned (ie. in the constructor and/or in the `set` method for the variable.)

If you don't want to manually validate, look into reflection.

Instead of hardcoding the names of fields, use annotations to mark fields for validation.  Then, use reflection to find marked fields.

```
enum ValidationType{
    NotNull,
    NotEmpty,
    NoDigits,
    NoLetters
}

@interface StringValidation {
    ValidationType validationType();
}

public class ValidationTest{
    @StringValidation(validationType = ValidationType.NotNull);
    String validateThisField;
}
```

In this example, your reflection code needs to search over fields in `ValidationTest`, checking for the `StringValidation` annotation.  If the annotation is present, look at the `ValidationType` and perform the requested validation.

Comment: I think this is a good solution but most of the classes I need to validate are auto generated classes from XSD's with JAXB. I can not use annotations for this classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [java reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) and call [Class#getDeclaredFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--) to retrieve all fields in a class, iterate over the array returned by this method and call the register and pass it [Field#getName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getName--)

```
for(Field field : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    validationRegisterer.register(field.getName(), 
        MandatoryFieldValidator.class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A class can have lots of fields and different validator implementations can be needed. I know which fields need which validator but I don't want to hardcode any of the field names.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Class object or an instance of the class, you can access any of its fields like this:

```
String property = "lastName";
Field field = targetObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(property);
field.setAccessible(true); //overrides private
field.set(targetObject, value);
```

But you can also get ALL fields using the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields() method to receive an Array of its fields.

Although I somewhat wonder if you can't just use the Bean Validation API and configure it using Annotations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think reflection is what I want. I don't want to hardcode any field names.